# Save several plots in the same loop (R)

Tags: r, plot

I cannot save several graphs in a single run of a loop. Looks to be dev. problem.

I am trying to write a code that takes a list of assets (tickers), downloads its price and in a single loop produces several graphs: Close price, returns, ACF function, etc...

The code looks like this:

```r
for (company in X) {

  MainCo <- unlist(company[1])

  getSymbols(MainCo, src = "yahoo", from = period_start, to = period_end)
  ts_main <- get(MainCo)

  png(paste0(MainCo,'_prices.png'))
  plot(ts_main[,6])
  dev.off()

  m_rts <- na.omit(Delt(na.omit(ts_main[,6])))

  png(paste0(MainCo,'_returns.png'))
  plot(m_rts)
  dev.off()

  png(paste0(MainCo,'_ACF.png'))
  acf(m_rts)
  dev.off()
}
```

I have tried different methods:

- use `dev.off()` only once at the end of the loop;
- use `graphics.off()` instead;
- use `dev.copy(...)` + `dev.off()` instead of `png(...)` + `dev.off()`

All mentioned above, either produce errors or only the last `ACF.png` graph. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

The key is hidden [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-July/166478.html), the `plot` needs to be printed - `print(plot(...))`

Comment: Don't use same name for all iteration. Vary it, and your code will work. For example, use `png(paste0("returns_", i, ".png"))`

Comment: @yarnabrina, to be honest, I don't see any difference. Instead of indexing, I am using different file names - the input is the same (string value). But, I have tested... does not work either, the same result. Thank you for advice

Comment: Your code doesn't work as new plots replace the old ones. If you use different names, it should work. If it doesn't work on your device, can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: And, in case it's not clear, you'll have to use `png(paste0("ACF_", i, ".png"))` along with `png(paste0("returns_", i, ".png"))`.

Comment: @yarnabrina, I have added asset ticker instead of `i`, check update, please. As a result, I have now ACF graph generated for all assets, but still no _prices.png and returns...

Comment: My previous comments were wrong in the sense I assumed you're using `i` as the loop counter. Sorry. I should have noticed correctly.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting all ACF plots, but single plots for price and range. However, I noticed that for ACF, you're using `MianCo`, and `MainCo` for the other two. You haven't defined `MianCo` in the provided code. What is it?

Comment: @yarnabrina, it's just typing error (in code its MainCo everywhere). Sorry, my bad. Corrected now.

Comment: @yarnabrina, check out the solution :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this one.